# Discord.py move_to

Tags: discord.py, member

I'd like to make a dc bot, and I want to kick members from voice channel by mention the user

```
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx):
    victim = ctx.message.mentions[0]
    await move_to(victim,none)
```

I use this code, but it don't work, it says "'Bot' object has no attribute 'move_members'"
How should I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can eject a member from voice by [`edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.edit)ing their `vocie_channel` to `None`.  I am also using a converter to get the member:

```
@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    await member.edit(voice_channel=None)
```

Comment: And how can I move the member to other channel? 681568940991971387 this is the ID and the channel name is "room1"

Comment: You can accept a channel as an argument using a converter, or you can use [`ctx.guild.get_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_channel)